# Bigquery UDF function - Sending query as argument to perform min/max/std_dv/count_of nulls etc functions

Tags: google-bigquery, max, user-defined-functions, min, standard-deviation

I am trying to create a Bigquery UDF function where I can send a query as an argument.
The function should calculate min/max/std_dv/count_of nulls functions on all the numerical columns and return the values.

I was trying to convert the field's data into an array but there is a limitation on size in an array and it won't work on big tables. I am attaching my attempt.

I am unable to create one and still trying to figure out if it is even possible in Bigquery.
Kindly help me figure it out.

```
DECLARE salary ARRAY <int64>;

SET salary = (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT salary FROM dataset.table)); 

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION analytical_fn(qty ARRAY <int64>)
   RETURNS FLOAT64
     LANGUAGE js AS """
     
      return Math.max.apply(null,qty);
     
   """;
   
select analytical_fn(salary)
```

Answer (score 1):

A function can be used to aggegate an array to several KPIs (min,max,etc.). Use standard SQL code, not JavaScript, otherwise all rows have to be processed at once.

```
DECLARE salary ARRAY <int64>;

SET salary = (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT 5  salary union all select 1 , union all  select 5   )); 

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION analytical_fn(qty ARRAY <int64>)
    AS ( (select struct( min(X) as min  , max(x) as max,STDDEV(X) as stddev, countif(X is Null) as count_of_nulls ) from unnest(qty) as X)  );
   
select analytical_fn(salary)  as summery
```

But in the the `array_agg` no `null` is allowed. Also think of using float as input array.

Comment: Can I skip array as it has a limit and this function is not working on a large dataset?

Comment: @Darshita A function needs the data and here is an array needed. Using a procedure is an option. Give the procedure the SQL query as a string and a list of parameters to query as well as a destination to write the table. The procedure can then build a sql query out of these inputs and runs that with `execute immediate`.